# create annotation with LongPress event

Tags: android, skmaps

I'm trying to add an annotation to the map with the "LongPress-event".

```
public void OnLongPress(SKScreenPoint point)
{
    SKCoordinate point1 = new SKCoordinate(point.GetX(), point.GetY());

    SKAnnotation anno1 = new SKAnnotation(10);
    anno1.Location = point1;
    anno1.MininumZoomLevel = 10;
    anno1.AnnotationType = SKAnnotation.SkAnnotationTypeBlue;

    _mapView.AddAnnotation(anno1, SKAnimationSettings.AnimationNone);

    System.Console.WriteLine(point1);
    System.Console.WriteLine(point);
    System.Console.WriteLine(anno1); 
}
```

From the Console.WriteLines I get following messages:

```
[540.9993896484375,1049.2178955078125]

SKScreenPoint [x=540.9994, y=1049.2179]

SKAnnotation [uniqueID=10, location=[540.9993896484375,1049.2178955078125], imagePath=null, imageSize=192, annotationType=33, mininumZoomLevel=10, offset=SKScreenPoint [x=0.0, y=0.0], annotationView=null]
```

I get the coordinates from my screen display. But I need the coordinates from the map.

How do I do that?
Can someone help me please? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert the screen point to a  "coordinate" via reverse geocoding:

```
  public void onLongPress(SKScreenPoint point) {
            SKCoordinate poiCoordinates = mapView.pointToCoordinate(point);
            final SKSearchResult place = SKReverseGeocoderManager
                    .getInstance().reverseGeocodePosition(poiCoordinates);

            SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation(GREEN_PIN_ICON_ID);

            annotation.setUniqueID(GREEN_PIN_ICON_ID);
            annotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_GREEN);


            annotation.setLocation(place.getLocation());
            annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm :)
Is there a possibility to save this annotation? When I reopen the map, this custom annotation is gone.
Is there also a possibility to add multiple annotations and save them?

Comment: What do you mean by "reopen the map" (please add a code snippet). Most If you're "resuming the map" then the annotations should still be there

Comment: "reopen the map" = close the app and open it again.
Now the annotation is still there. I made a little mistake... I thought, that I can use the same annotation-id as my other static annotation, which I set with a custom SKCoordinate :)